# Good Source for German Tank Problem

Tags: statistics

I would like to teach the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) to bright students with little prerequisites. They are 16 year old high school students with a lot of maths competition experience, but no prior knowledge of statistics

Does anybody have a source that explains the reasoning behind the frequentist and bayesian approach in an accessible manner?

Comment: They are actually 16 year old high school students with a lot of experience from maths competitions. So the source could be abstract and mathematically precise, but should not expect the reader to know a lot about frequentist and bayesian statistics.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Namaste Thank you for your links which are interesting. I already have a rough idea of the two approaches in general, but I would like to understand them more in the context of the German Tank Problem. The wikipedia article I linked gives some explanation, but with too little details for me to follow it.

Comment: @Namaste It is helpful and I appreciate your sources. It just wanted to make sure what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: I will be hearing a generalist talk on this in a couple days (see [this abstract](https://sites.google.com/view/nesmaafall2019meeting/abstracts)) so you may want to email the speaker (who is a good expositor) as to sources that approach things from the point of view you are looking for.

Comment: @krisman Thank you, this helped a lot.